# Ubuntu Software only shows apps installed in the current session NOT ALL installed apps

Tags: software-center

Don't know how this has happened but I have just noticed that Ubuntu Software is only showing apps installed in the current session NOT ALL installed apps...

I have literally just done a clean install of Ubuntu 22.04 48hrs ago so, it really shouldn't be broken.

Is there a way to fix this issue? I don't want to have to reinstall my whole system again.

Comment: Are those other applications really installed? Use apt to check. Do applications (and data) vanish from your system after a restart?

Comment: @user535733 They are all really installed. Nothing vanishes.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question yet again for the sake of helping the community.

The following resolved the issue completely:

$ sudo killall snap-store

$ sudo snap refresh

Now reopen ubuntu software ...et voilà!